# How to fetch data from backend API in next.js framework

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a table of records which takes data from backend springboot server and renders on UI using next.js framework of react. Whats the best and most optimal way to achieve this

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch or https://axios-http.com/docs/intro, same as in react.

Answer (score 0):

now you can use `fetch()` on both client and server side code
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/supported-browsers-features#server-side-polyfills